# Is it possible to save only half of a symmetric matrix to save the memory?

Tags: matlab, matrix, large-data

There is a large matrix that is used in `Ax=b` type problem.  **A** is symmetric. Is there any algorithm to let us save only half of the matrix and do operation like `x=A\b` on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll only save half the memory, but you can do this by creating a flat version of the matrix, saving that, then unflattening it.  The extra time required probably doesn't make the saving worthwhile, mind:

```
% pretend this is symettric...
A = rand(10, 10);

% store it as a flat list
flatA = [];
for k = 1:size(A,1)
    flatA = [flatA; A([1:k],k)];
end

save('flatA.mat', 'flatA');

% undo
N = (-1 + (1+4*2*length(flatA))^0.5)/2;
newA = NaN(N,N); 
cur = 1;
for k = 1:N
    len = k;
    newA(1:len, k) = flatA(cur:cur+len-1);
    cur = cur + len;
end
% real A cannot have NaNs or this trick fails
newA(isnan(newA)) = newA(isnan(newA'))';
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea, but I haven't tested it out. If your symmetric matrix is positive definite, do a Cholesky decomposition of the symmetric matrix, A, giving you A = U*U'. If you store U as a sparse matrix using MATLAB's builtin sparse matrix, you have everything you need, and you've used roughly half the memory. Since its using MATLAB's sparse matrix type, you have operate on it using standard MATLAB functions, as long as you remember that A = U*U'

For example, to compute A*x = b, use x = U'\U\b. Unlike the other proposed solutions, MATLAB will never be actually using a full matrix internally, and will even use accelerated solvers that will take advantage of the fact that you're only solving with triangular. The cost is that to solve a single system, you've actually running the backslash operator twice (see above). However, that's the price you pay for never instantiating the full matrix.

Comment: I'd give rep if you test it out and give a [MWE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show that it works!

Answer (score 1):

If you extract the upper triangular part and convert to a sparse matrix, it should save memory.  This technique is reasonably quick.

```
% Create a symmetric matrix
A = rand(1000);
A = A + A';

% Extract the upper triangular part
B = sparse(triu(A))              % This is the important line, the rest is just checking.

% Undo
BB = full(B);
C = BB + BB' - diag(diag(BB));

% Check correct
assert(all(A(:) == C(:)));

% Save matrices
save('A.mat', 'A');
save('B.mat', 'B');

% Get file sizes
infoA = dir('A.mat'); infoA.bytes
infoB = dir('B.mat'); infoB.bytes
```

---

EDIT to clarify things for woodchips

The above solution demonstrates a way of saving matrices with less file space.  The matrix `B` also takes up less memory than the original matrix `A`.  If you want to do linear algebraic operations on `B`, that works perfectly well.  Compare

```
b = rand(1000);
fullTriUA = triu(A);
sparseTriUA = sparse(fullTriUA);  %same as B above
fullResult = fullTriUA\b;
sparseResult = sparseTriUA\b;
assert(all(fullResult(:) == sparseResult(:)))
```

Comment: Yes, but then to use the matrix, you force the user to convert back to a full matrix, and then recover the entire matrix anyway!!!!! This not only does not save memory, it generates several copies of the matrix as full matrices. It takes up several times MORE memory than the original matrix required.

Comment: @woodchips: You've misunderstood.  The extra copies of the matrix are only for restoring from file.  See my edit.

Comment: Yes. But when you do restore the array, you create multiple copies of that array. The disk space to store an array is rarely if ever likely to be an issue, but the RAM is often so. I interpret the question to be one of memory usage, since the user still wishes to use operations like A\b using the minimized array. If so, then making multiple copies of a large array will surely be a problem. Clarification is needed here.

Comment: Sparse matrix only save you memory if the original matrix has less than third of non-zero elements. In this case it's more than half. Try `whos A B`. `B` actually takes more space than `A`.

Comment: @yuk: `B` takes up less memory than `A` for 6x6 matrices or bigger.  (Tested on R2011a and R2010b.)  For really big matrices, it approaches 3/4 of the memory footprint of `A`.  Maybe you forgot to take the upper triangular portion.

Comment: @woodchips: As I tried to clarify: the user doesn't need to convert back to a full matrix in order to do operations like `A\b`.  MATLAB can happily do matrix manipulation on sparse matrices.

Comment: @Richie: I just repeated 3 first lines from your code (skipping comments) and compared `A` and `B` size with `whos`. `A` is 8,000,000 bytes and `B` is 8,016,008 bytes. MATLAB R2011a Windows x64.

Comment: @yuk: Very interesting. On Win32, the size of `A` is the same, but the size of `B` is only 6 010 004 bytes.  I presume the difference is due to bigger pointers in the 64 bit case.

Comment: Instead of `C = BB + BB' - diag(diag(BB));` you can do this: `C = BB + tril(BB', -1);` It should save some processing.