# For-Loop for finding combinations of springs?

Tags: function, matlab, for-loop

I need to use a for-loop in a function in order to find spring constants of all possible combinations of springs in series and parallel. I have 5 springs with data therefore I found the spring constant (K) of each in a new matrix by using polyfit to find the slope (using F=Kx).

I have created a function that does so, however it returns data not in a matrix, but as individual outputs. So instead of KP (Parallel)= [1 2 3 4 5] it says KP=1, KP=2, KP=3, etc. Because of this, only the final output is stored in my workspace. Here is the code I have for the function. Keep in mind that the reason I need to use the +2 in the for loop for b is because my original matrix K with all spring constants is ten columns, with every odd number being a 0. Ex: K=[1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5] --- This is because my original dataset to find K (slope) was ten columns wide.

```
function[KP,KS]=function_name1(K)
L=length(K);
c=1;
for a=1:2:L
    for b=a+2:2:L
        KP=K(a)+K(b)
        KS=1/((1/K(a))+(1/K(b)))
    end
end
c=c+1;
```

and then a program calling that function

[KP,KS]=function_name1(K);

What I tried: - Suppressing and unsuppressing lines of code (unsuccessful)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try K = K(K~=0) to remove the zeros.  The main problem is that in every loop you are overwriting the values of KP and KS.

Answer (score 1):

hmmm...

your code seems workable, but you aren't dealing with things in the most practical manner

I'd start be redimensioning K so that it makes sense, that is that it's 5 spaces wide instead of your current 10 - you'll see why in a minute.

Then I'd adjust KP and KS to the size that you want (I'm going to do a 5X5 as that will give all the permutations - right now it looks like you are doing some triangular thing, I wouldn't worry too much about space unless you were to do this for say 50,000 spring constants or so)

So my code would look like this

```
function[KP,KS]=function_name1(K)
L=length(K);
KP = zeros(L);
KS = zeros(l);
c=1;
for a=1:L
    for b=1:L
        KP(a,b)=K(a)+K(b)
        KS(a,b)=1/((1/K(a))+(1/K(b)))
    end
end
c=c+1;
```

then when you want the parallel combination of springs 1 and 4 KP(1,4) or KP(4,1) will do the trick

Comment: How would I eliminate the zeros in K? Seems easy at first glance but I'm kind of stuck on that.

But using  KP(a,b) gave me exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, saw the above comment, it worked, giving me a perfect 5x5 matrix! Thank you. Is there a way to delete repetitive data? Example: the matrix point 3,1 and 1,3 is the same because its the same two springs in parallel (or series).

Comment: I'm not frequently browsing StackOverflow. There are several strategies you could use to reduce the size of the matrix. The choice really depends on what you want to do downstream of this code. You could use the solution that's discussed here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261296/is-it-possible-to-save-only-half-of-a-symmetric-matrix-to-save-the-memory